# How to train my app using dialogflow API's?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to train my app using API. I am using my own UI to validate the intents and just want to validate one by one for particular intent. To get intent I am using this api `https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query?v=20150910` but don't know how to train any particular intent for any sample.

Comment: Have you tried the Dialogflow getting started guide? http://docs.dialogflow.com/

If you have can you clarify your question with any training phrase examples in intents and what you tried to do any what you expect?

Comment: I want to know for training, Is there any API available?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for Dialogflow's training feature but you can accomplish the same result by looking at your logs and using Dialogflow's [update intent API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/patch) and passing in new (or removing) [training phrases](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/Shared.Types/Intent)